# my background image is not fitting inside the bootstrap jumbotron

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

> i am making the full size image which will cover whole jumbotron but the image is comning out of jumbotron,can anyone help me to sort out this problem

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="jumbotron" style="position:relative;">
            <img src="images/bg_image%20(1).jpg" alt="jumbotron" style="position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; background-size:cover;">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why you use position's in jumbotron and image?

Comment: i want to fit the image in jumbotron

Comment: The image should be fit to the jumbotron. Are you setting the jumbotron´s values?

Comment: It's not necessary to use that all style's, Refer my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use class `.img-responsive`. Obviously image will contain enough width.

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="position:relative;">
      <img src="Add a new customer   SmartStore.NET administration.png" class="img-responsive" alt="jumbotron" style="position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; background-size:cover;">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to do inline style sheet for that, just use `img-responsive` class in image,  refer the below answer.

---

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <img src="images/bg_image%20(1).jpg" alt="jumbotron" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So instead of using an image tag you could simply link the image via background property of CSS. Refer to the code below:

```
<style>
.jumbo_bg{
 background: url('../images/bg_image%20(1).jpg');
 background-position: center center;
 background-size: cover;
 height: auto /* or if you wish to give any height instead of auto use any px value like 150px;*/
}
</style>

<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="jumbotron jumbo_bg">
        <!-- Add Your text here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

This should work fine for all screen sizes.